# How to create concurrent sorted map based on value?

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap, java.util.concurrent, concurrentskiplistmap

I need to create a concurrent map with `<String, AtomicLong>` parameters. The map should be sorted based on it's value, when I increment the `AtomicLong`, it should also balance itself.

The problem with `ConcurrentSkipListMap` is that it cannot sort the map based on its value. TreeMap is not a concurrent data structure.

I'm looking for a data structure so that complexity of insertion should be `O(log(n))` like `TreeMap` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap`. Also, the values are not unique so that there may be multiple map entries that have same numeric value in `AtomicLong`.

Comment: This sounds complicated. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind, i'm working for an analytics project so it's basically a counter map. Let's say the key is an url and the values are the counts of visits. I looked at the libraries like Guava but couldn't find and appropriate data structure for this case. :/

Comment: Did you consider using `synchronized` for access on the map and the values and instead use a simple `TreeMap` and `Integer`?

Comment: Yes but the problem is TreeMap is also keeps the list sorted based on key and even though I use some hacks to sort it based on value, when I increment the counter, it cannot recognise the change and balance the map again.

Comment: Did you try using two Collections? `HashSet<String, UrlCounter>` and `PriorityQueue<UrlCounter>`, where `class UrlCounter{ String url; int count = 0; }`? (or TreeSet). I still would suggest that you describe your complete problem a bit better, so that more appropriate solutions can be given. Also see this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I have been working on a distributed analytics service and each node in the cluster is responsible for a set of counters. Also each node has multiple threads that can access the internal UrlCounter objects. When a user views an url, the system automatically routes the request to the node that is responsible for that key. If the key (url string) exists in internal map, i need to increment the counter in UrlCounter, otherwise i need create a new AtomicLong(1) and put it to the map. The UrlCounter instances in map must be sorted and we should be able to get the top N url without any latency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57330/discussion-between-burak-emre-and-absurd-mind).